# Creating a function that predicts the failure probability of a certain processor

Tags: java, function, probability

My program (in Java) has an object called a Processor, which can undergo an iteration event.

Each processor has the following fields:
`double lambda` - decay index;
`double failProb` - probability of failure per iteration;
`int age` - number of iterations the processor had been active;
`boolean failed` - describe whether the processor has "failed"

During each iteration event, the following things take place:

1. `age` increments by 1;
2. `failPorb` is updated according to this function: `failProb=1-Math.exp(-lambda*age);`
3. A random number (0~1) is compared with `failProb`, and if comparison evaluates true--`random-number < failProb`--, the field `failed` becomes `true`

In summary, every iteration may cause Processor to "fail", and the probability of failing increases with each iteration.

The question is this, how can I write a function in Processor that predicts the probability that the processor will fail within the next `x` iterations (that errs on the side of concluded greater failure probability, if necessary?)

Attempted solutions:

1:

```
public double predictFailProb(int x){
    return(1-Math.exp(-lambda*(age+x)));
}
```

The above does not work because it only gives the `failProb` at the last of the x-iteration time period, without considering that the Processor might have failed before that point. In other words this really predicts `failProb` when the Processor is at age `x+current_age`

2:

```
public double predictFailProb(int x){
    double t=1;
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
        t*=1-(1-Math.exp(-lambda*(age+i)));
    }
    return (1-t);
}
```

Theoretically, the above should compute the probability that the Processor *doesn't* fail for the next `x` iterations, and then return the compliment of that value. This, if functional, feels rudimentary and performance-intensive. I have the feeling that there is probably a much simpler expression for the same function.

Comment: What is the question? :) Also, has this really to do with java/programming, or is it a question about maths/statistics?

Comment: It isn't the question about java - rather it's a question about uniform and non-uniform probability distributions... (as @giorgiga noticed)

Comment: I believe I have figured out what I need to do, i.e. solution 2, but I think it can be done more efficiently by a different function, if that makes sense.

Comment: You could solve this with really clever maths, or you could brute force it with Java by running the scenario n times, as a luddite myself I'd probably do the latter, but i'm sure you're better than that ;)

Comment: How would I rephrase these for the snobs at Math S.E.?

Comment: It looks as if you can express it by an explicit formula: negate, multiply probs for not failing, move prod_a e^lam * a into the exponent e^(sum lam * a), use gaussian sum formula to obtain explicit expression for the sum, done. I'll write it up in a minute... Math S.E. snobs are already here, don't worry ;)

Comment: What is lambda? A constant, or what is called a lambda in functional programming or something else? I don't share your concerns about performance for small values of x. You could test it, which would help in 3 aspects: a) You get values, to compare your maybe clever math solution against. b) You can test your expectation, that performance is an issue. c) The observed values might help you in finding a more clever math solution.

Comment: @userunknown `lambda` has nothing to do with the lambda calculus: it's the decay rate of the survival probability of a processor. If `lambda=0`, then the processor is immortal. If `lambda` is very large, it breaks almost immediately. If the value lambda is tiny, and `x` is in the order of hundreds of billions, then an explicit formula is clearly preferable to a loop. Fortunately, a loop is not necessary, see solution below.

Comment: the `1-(1-` in `1-(1-Math.exp(-lambda*(age+i)));` looks a bit redundant. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explicit formula for failure within `x` steps.

Given:

- Let `A_k` be the event that the processor fails in step `k`.
- The probability for failure in `k-th` step is given by `P[A_k] = 1 - exp(-lambda * (age + k))`

We want to compute the probability that the processor will fail within `x` steps.

It holds:

```
P[fails within first x steps]
  = 1 - P[does not fail within x steps]
  = 1 - P[AND_{k = 1}^x not(A_k)]
  = 1 - prod_{k=1}^x P[not(A_k)]     // independence assumption
  = 1 - prod_{k=1}^x (1 - P[A_k])
  = 1 - prod_{k=1}^x (1 - 1 + exp(-lambda * (age + k)))
  = 1 - prod_{k=1}^x exp(-lambda * (age + k))
  = 1 - exp(-lambda * age * x - lambda * sum_{k=1}^x k)
  = 1 - exp(-lambda * age * x) * exp(-lambda * x * (x + 1) / 2)
```

Thus, in Java, it can be computed in constant time as follows:

```
double probFailureWithin(int steps, int age, double lambda) {
  return 
    1.0 - 
    Math.exp(-lambda * age * steps) * 
    Math.exp(-lambda * steps * (steps + 1) / 2.0);
}
```

Here is a full series of experiments that confirm that this explicit formula is right:

```
double probFailureWithin(int steps, int age, double lambda) {
  return 
    1.0 - 
    Math.exp(-lambda * age * steps) * 
    Math.exp(-lambda * steps * (steps + 1) / 2.0);
}

boolean randFailureWithin(int steps, int age, double lambda) {
  for (int k = 1; k <= steps; k++) {
    double failProb = 1 - Math.exp(-lambda * (age + k));
    if (Math.random() < failProb) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

double bruteforceFailureWithin(int steps, int age, double lambda) {
  double nonFailureProb = 1.0;
  for (int k = 1; k <= steps; k++) {
    nonFailureProb *= Math.exp(-lambda * (age + k));
  }
  return 1.0 - nonFailureProb;
}

void runExperiment(int steps, int age, double lambda, int reps) {
  int numFailures = 0;
  for (int rep = 0; rep < reps; rep++) {
    if (randFailureWithin(steps, age, lambda)) {
      numFailures++;
    }
  }
  double empiricalProb = numFailures / (double)reps;
  double predictedProb = probFailureWithin(steps, age, lambda);
  double bruteforceProb = bruteforceFailureWithin(steps, age, lambda);
  System.out.println(
    "a = " + age + 
    " l = " + lambda + 
    " s = " + steps +
    " Empirical: " + empiricalProb + 
    " Predicted: " + predictedProb + 
    " BruteForce: " + bruteforceProb
  );
}

void runExperiments(int reps) {
  for (double lambda : new double[]{0.7, 0.5, 0.1, 0.01, 0.0001}) {
    for (int age : new int[]{0, 1, 10, 1000, 10000}) {
      for (int steps : new int[]{0, 1, 10, 1000, 10000}) {
         runExperiment(steps, age, lambda, reps);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Simply `runExperiments(10000)` or something like that, and compare the values of:

- Empirical random value obtained from repeated experiment
- Explicit formula
- Brute-force formula with a loop

You will see that the explicit formula is exactly the same as the brute-force multiplication approach, and that both these formulas are pretty close to the empirical results.

An excerpt:

```
a = 500 l = 1.0E-4 s = 1 
Empirical:  0.049054 
Predicted:  0.04886569368574745 
BruteForce: 0.04886569368574745

a = 500 l = 1.0E-4 s = 10 
Empirical:  0.396329 
Predicted:  0.39679610193504744 
BruteForce: 0.39679610193504766

a = 500 l = 1.0E-4 s = 100 
Empirical:  0.995945 
Predicted:  0.9959336114191201 
BruteForce: 0.9959336114191201
```